# XSLT - interlink attributes from different child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, linked-list

I have the following XML file that stores movies and actors:

```
<database
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">
    <movies>
        <movie movieID="1">
            <title>Movie 1</title>
            <actors>
                <actor actorID="1"></actor>
                <actor actorID="2"></actor>
            </actors>
        </movie>
    </movies>

    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1">
            <name>Bob</name>
        </actor>
        <actor actorID="2">
            <name>Mike</name>
        </actor>
    </actors>
</database>
```

I want to connect actorID from `database/movies/movie/actors/actor` with the actorID from `database/actors/actor` and display actors' names:

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="selectActors" select="database/actors/actor[@actorID]"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputRoot" select="/"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="database/movies/movie"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
        Title:
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <br/>
        Actors:
        <xsl:for-each select="actors/actor[@actorID=$selectActors]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$inputRoot/database/actors/actor/name"/>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the end result that I want to display:

```
Title: Movie 1
Actors: Bob
    Mike
```

I cannot get actor names to display on my page. I am not sure if I have interlinked my actorID's correctly as I'm very new to XSLT in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the XPath in your `for-each` and the one in your `value-of` but a more efficient (and more elegant) approach than what you're attempting is to use keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kActor" match="database/actors/actor" use="@actorID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="database/movies/movie"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Title: ', title)"/>
    <br />
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kActor', actors/actor/@actorID)" />
    <br />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="actor">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <br />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<div>
  Title: Movie 1<br />Actors: Bob<br />Mike<br /><br />
</div>
```

And just so you can see what was incorrect with your XPath, here is how you could have fixed your existing solution to work correctly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="selectActors" select="database/actors/actor"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="database/movies/movie"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="movie">
    Title:
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <br/>
    Actors:
    <xsl:for-each
      select="$selectActors[@actorID = current()/actors/actor/@actorID]">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, JLRishe. It's good to know a more efficient approach to solve this problem, and it all makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Glad to help. I've also made a modification above so you can see how the XPaths could have been modified to work correctly.